# Problem with redirecting to Login Page on logging out in React-Redux App

Tags: reactjs, redux, logout

On logout, I want the app to redirect to the Login page. Currently, when I click the Logout link, it remains at '/landPage' but with no content.

I've tried using this.props.history.push('/login') and wrapping the component in withRouter but that doesn't work. I am using 
Link but that isn't working either.

What should I try next?

navbar.js

```
class NavAuth extends Component {

    state = {}

    onLogout = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.localStorage.clear();
        this.props.logoutUser();
        // this.props.history.push('/login');
    }

    render () {
        const { isAuthenticated, user } = this.props.auth;
    return (
        <Navbar bg="light" expand="sm">
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav"/>
          <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
           {isAuthenticated ? (
            <Nav className="ml-auto">
              <Link to="/chat">Chat</Link>
              <Link to="/login" onClick = {this.onLogout}>Logout</Link>
             </Nav> 
            ) :(
             <Nav className="ml-auto">
                <Link to="/registration">Registration</Link>
                <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
             </Nav>
            )}
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    )}
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.auth
  });

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
   {logoutUser}
  )(NavAuth);
```

Comment: Are you using react-bootstrap?

Comment: Yes I am using react-bootstrap.

Comment: You can use `if (!isAuthenticated) return <Redirect to='/login' />` before your `return ()` statement and import `Redirect` from `import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';`

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but it makes the navbar disappear altogether on starting up the app. When I do login and then logout, it still doesn't redirect to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can redirect to login page. You can check your isAuthenticated for non true value.

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
class NavAuth extends Component {

    state = {}

    onLogout = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.localStorage.clear();
        this.props.logoutUser();
        // this.props.history.push('/login');
    }

    render () {
        const { isAuthenticated, user } = this.props.auth;
        if (!isAuthenticated) return <Redirect to='/login' />
    return (
        <Navbar bg="light" expand="sm">
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav"/>
          <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">

            <Nav className="ml-auto">
              <Link to="/chat">Chat</Link>
              <Link to="/login" onClick = {this.onLogout}>Logout</Link>
             </Nav> 
            ) :(
             <Nav className="ml-auto">
                <Link to="/registration">Registration</Link>
                <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
             </Nav>

            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    )}
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.auth
  });

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
   {logoutUser}
  )(NavAuth);
```

Comment: I tried it but it makes the navbar disappear altogether on starting up the app. When I do login and then logout, it still doesn't redirect to the login page.

Comment: Check your isAuthenticated value it will be true in If its not redirecting then it means you are not removing user info from local storage or what ever way you are using for user state persistence.

Comment: The "isAuthenticated" state in the authorization reducer was set to true when it shouldn't have been. Once I corrected that the Link to="/login"> worked.